# shuffle a javascript array of objects every 10 seconds using object id

Tags: javascript

I need to shuffle this array every 10 seconds By object ID.
Here I have only 5 entities but I need to do this for n entity.

```
[{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Got",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Cat",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Dog",
    "price": 270
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Cow",
    "price": 70
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Ant",
    "price": 170
  }]
```

I have tried this.. This function not giving actual output

```
startRandom() {
    if (this.rndm) {
        this.temData = []
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            this.temData.push(this.tempData[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1  ])
        }
        this.tempData = this.temData
    }
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: And you can use setTimeInterval() on it for 10000 ms

Comment: In `SetTimInterval` take two random number between 0 and `array.length - 1` and `swap` them

Comment: NO.. I am trying to shuffle using object ID and it will shuffle every 10sec @BeshambherChaukhwan

Comment: Take one object or take them by object ids it will have the same effect. But if you want to take out the ids only then do the shuffling on the array `objectArray.map(o => o.id)`

Comment: Can you please solve my problem and give me a solution @BeshambherChaukhwan

Comment: i finished the code but i cant post it because the post is closed. chat me i can send u the code

Comment: Take the code from the first comment link and wrap it inside a setTimeInterval (). I cannot make an answer since the question has been closed. Study more about these functions if you aren't comfortable with object arrays. Its easy trust me.

Comment: @seriously put it on stackbliz or ideone and you can share the link via comment here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpew596t/

Comment: Got it. thanks a lot @BeshambherChaukhwan